# ARM Device (Cubieboard) Image Write fails (Phoenix Suite)

Tags: android, ubuntu, arm

I am trying to write Android/Ubuntu images on Cubieboard's NAND Memory using Phoenix Suite software (Windows 10) as described below.

http://docs.cubieboard.org/tutorials/cb1/installation/cb1_lubuntu_nand_install
http://docs.cubieboard.org/tutorials/cb1/installation/cb1_android_4.0.x_nand_install

Images downloaded from official cubieboard download server:

```
http://dl.cubieboard.org/model/CubieBoard1/Image/
```

I managed to install Phoenix Suite, Android USB Drivers, but I fail on writing the NAND memory. I press the FEL button, insert the USB cable, release the FEL but Phoenix Suite is not reacting properly = Image write mode won't start and manual write mode says - Not Connected.

Is anyone of you aware of any way how to find out what is going on under the hood? (Any way I could debug this process)
Can I try other option of writing NAND's memory than Phoenix Suite?

Thank you for help.

PS: The device's red LED is acting similarly as in instruction videos, so I believe it is not bricked.